# Create a view that contains in every row data that comes from six different records[PostgreSQL]

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, sql-function

I have a table that contains gas station prices. Every Gas Station has six price records for the different fuel types(Diesel,regular,super) and service type(Auto Service, Full service). For example I have the price records for the gas station with the "id_gas_station" = 155 in the table "gas_station_prices"

```
id_price|price_gas_station|id_gas_station|id_fuel_type|id_service_type
3041    |2.29             |155           |2           |1
2631    |2.52             |155           |1           |1
3861    |2.43             |155           |1           |2    
4681    |1.84             |155           |3           |2    
3451    |1.93             |155           |3           |1    
4271    |2.2              |155           |2           |2
```

I have two catalogs that contains the fuel type and the service type

fuel_type catalog:

```
id_fuel_type |name_fuel_type
1            |SUPER
2            |REGULAR
3            |DIESEL
```

service_type catalog:

```
id_service_type |name_service_type
1               |FULL SERVICE
2               |AUTO SERVICE
```

I need to create a SQL VIEW that contains the union of the six record prices of the column "price_gas_station" in a single row for every gas_station as FOLLOWS:

```
id_gas_station|fs_sup_p |fs_reg_p |fs_die_p |as_sup_p |as_reg_p|as_die_p|
155           |2.52     |2.29     |1.93     |2.43     |2.2     |1.84
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT id_gas_station,
       MAX(CASE WHEN id_fuel_type = 1 AND 
                     id_service_type = 1 
                THEN price_gas_station 
           END) AS fs_sup_p, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN id_fuel_type = 2 AND 
                     id_service_type = 1
                THEN price_gas_station 
           END) AS fs_reg_p, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN id_fuel_type = 3 AND 
                     id_service_type = 1
                THEN price_gas_station 
           END) AS fs_die_p, 
       ... etc
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id_gas_station
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using a CROSSTAB (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
'
SELECT
    gsp.id_gas_station,
    LOWER(LEFT(st.name_service_type,4) || ft.name_fuel_type) AS price_type,
    gsp.price_gas_station
FROM
    gas_station_prices gsp
JOIN
    fuel_type ft
    ON  (ft.id_fuel_type = gsp.id_fuel_type)
JOIN
    service_type st
    ON  (st.id_service_type = gsp.id_service_type)
ORDER BY
    1,2
'
) AS ct (
id_gas_station INT,
auto_diesel FLOAT,
auto_regular FLOAT,
auto_super FLOAT,
full_diesel FLOAT,
full_regular FLOAT,
full_super FLOAT
);
```

Giorgos solution should be just as good - maybe more readable, too? It is a matter of preference for the most part. I just wanted to show you an alternative.